# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource houseDocumenter/House.hbm.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, pojo

Getting this error all the time.
I'm using eclipse luna
My House.hbm.xml validates in eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 24-Oct-2015 10:24:27 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="houseDocumenter.House" table="HOUSE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="imageURL" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="IMAGEURL" />
        </property>
        <property name="propertyAddress" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROPERTYADDRESS" />
        </property>
        <property name="evaluationCompleteYN" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EVALUATIONCOMPLETEYN" />
        </property>
        <property name="evaluationText" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EVALUATIONTEXT" />
        </property>
        <property name="followUpYN" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FOLLOWUPYN" />
        </property>
        <property name="followUpText" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FOLLOWUPTEXT" />
        </property>
        <property name="originatingWebURL" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ORIGINATINGWEBURL" />
        </property>
        <property name="price" type="int">
            <column name="PRICE" />
        </property>
        <property name="valueForMoney" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VALUEFORMONEY" />
        </property>
        <property name="valuationNotes" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VALUATIONNOTES" />
        </property>
        <property name="schoolNameKey" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHOOLNAMEKEY" />
        </property>
        <property name="schoolRatingKey" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SCHOOLRATINGKEY" />
        </property>
        <property name="broadbandProviderKey" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="BROADBANDPROVIDERKEY" />
        </property>
        <property name="broadbandSpeed" type="int">
            <column name="BROADBANDSPEED" />
        </property>
        <property name="mobilePhoneConnectivity" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MOBILEPHONECONNECTIVITY" />
        </property>
        <property name="transportLinksOkYN" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TRANSPORTLINKSOKYN" />
        </property>
        <property name="tenure">
            <column name="TENURE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm trying to use Hibernate to produce the dictionary pojos for my system.
It worked once but then gave up.

I'd appreciate any help!

The Hibernate error message window contains the following:

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource houseDocumenter/House.hbm.xml
Could not parse mapping document from resource houseDocumenter/House.hbm.xml
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource houseDocumenter/House.hbm.xml
Could not parse mapping document from resource houseDocumenter/House.hbm.xml
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [tenure] not found on houseDocumenter.House
field [tenure] not found on houseDocumenter.House
```

Comment: Could you post the whole stack-trace?

Comment: I'm a newbie, can you please tell me how I get one?

Comment: @Tunaki have added the only messages I get to the end of my question.

Comment: The eror speaks for itself: "field [tenure] not found on houseDocumenter.House". Do you have a field named `tenur` in `House` class?

Comment: @Tenuki Yes that's where my problem lies. The pojo is out of date since I added "tenure" to the house.hbm.xml file, and I want to update the pojo from the current state of the xml file. I could edit the pojo and put "tenure" in there, but that is precisely what I want Hibernate to do for me! Perhaps I don't understand what Hibernate does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my particular problem. The hbm.xml wanted a type.

Previous:

```
<property name="tenure">
            <column name="TENURE" />
        </property>
```

Correct:

```
 <property name="tenure" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TENURE" />
        </property>
```

Little things mean a lot.

Thanks to everyone who looked.